# Profile comment activity - visited/unvisited link colours mixed up?

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, activity-tab

I was looking at a my comment history and noticed the following:

> [image: Mixed up question title colours]

I feel like the `:visited` colour is used when the link hasn't been visited yet. All around the network links usually become greyed out after visiting them, but in this case they turn from grey to blue for some reason.

The `:hover` colour also hints that normally the darker blue should be visible instead of the grey.

Example: [my profile's comments activity section](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1344955/djdavid98?tab=activity&sort=comments) 
Tested with latest stable (`47.0.2526.111`) and canary (`50.0.2626.0`) Chrome

Comment: I cannot repro.

Comment: @PythonMaster I've added the browser versions where I noticed this issue

Comment: Reproduced, but I think it's by design - all grey text that is a hyperlink works like this (e.g. the date on this comment).